# .htaccess rewrite condition trailing slash only for specific directories

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have this rule which works great and adds a trailing slash for every directory on my site.
How Can I add trailing slashes for only certain directories such /courses/ ? I don't want every directory / path to have a trailing slash.

```
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/[^\.]+[^/]$
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1/ [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(courses|foo|bar)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1/ [R=301,L]
```

Should work where `courses`, `foo` and `bar` are directories that you want to add a trailing slash to.

Comment: Thanks that worked! how about multiple levels. Would something like this work?



`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(course|course/online-courses/illness)$`

Comment: That should work fine. If you have any problems with it shout.

Answer (score 0):

Think this will work:

```
<Files .htaccess>
    order allow,deny
    deny from all
</Files>

Options All -Indexes
IndexIgnore *

# Don't add trailing slash for /include/
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/include/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1

# Respond to /include/ with 404 instead of 403
RedirectMatch 404 ^/include(/?|/.*)$
```

Comment: Essentially the same thing that James said. Just make sure you're not creating an infinite loop with the order.