# .htaccess rewrite only files in a certain directory

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I found this question which is similar to my request [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6034824/htaccess-rewrite-condition-trailing-slash-only-for-specific-directories), but I'm not sure how to modify it to my need

I want to ...

a) Drop the directory (edited, forgot to mention)

- Note, I'm just using the directory as a container to keep this rule
  separate from affecting other files. Maybe there's a better way to
  work with a range of files only, such as a specific string in the
  file name? Directory seemed like the simplest solution.)

b) Drop the file extension

c) Replace it with a trailing slash

... on files contained only within the /categories/ directory

So the effect is that `website.com/categories/My-File-Name.php` becomes `website.com/My-File-Name/`

This is what I've tried so far:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/categories/$
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)/$ /categories/$1.php [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/categories/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /categories/$1.php [L]
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, I edited my question to include a forgotten requirement