# .htaccess add "/" to specific or all folder in my domain except domain.com

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I want to make when people insert on browser url: domain.com/foo redirect to domain.com/foo/ ( foo|bar|etc , are real folder ) I read this  [.htaccess rewrite condition trailing slash only for specific directories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6034824/htaccess-rewrite-condition-trailing-slash-only-for-specific-directories)
but i thought my problem is with apache , some people said Apache put de slash to folder but for a reason , not mine, how i should now that?
this are the redirect lines on my .htaccess

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteEngine On

#without www 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.(.+)$  [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

#html to php
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ $1.php [nc]

#index on folder
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^(.+[^/])$ $1/index.html [L]

*****************************************************
#this is the last rewrite I inserted trying to do so, without success
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(foo|bar|etc)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1/ [R=301,L]
*****************************************************
```

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code in your root .htaccess:

```
DirectorySlash On

RewriteBase /
RewriteEngine On

#without www 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.(.+)$  [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

*****************************************************
#this is the last rewrite I inserted trying to do so, without success
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(foo|bar|etc)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1/ [R=301,L]
*****************************************************

#html to php
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ $1.php [L,NC]

#index on folder
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^(.+[^/])$ $1/index.html [L]
```

Comment: Still not working and dind't see any different, any further ideas @anubhava ?

Comment: for which URL it didn't work. Try this in a new browser to avoid 301 caching problem.

Comment: the 301 is what i have since i begin with and still nothing change, i'm testing on 3 different browsers and clearing cookies everytime. i'm testing on alvidart.com not a localhost server.

Comment: none of the three , (alvidart.com/foo|alvidart.com/bar|alvidart.com/etc)